# Android - how to get CardViews with ImageViews inside into a grid

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-imageview, android-cardview

I have some square images and want to put them in rows of 3 that fit the width of the screen, while retaining the aspect ratio of the images. This can be done quite easily. However, I also want to put each ImageView into a CardView (square cards), but when I do this there are issues.
Instead of being the height of the image, the card is really long. I'm not sure what's gone wrong here.
Below is the code that worked until I put the first ImageView into a CardView.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/square1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/main_dark"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/square2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/main"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/square3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/main_light"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why not create a CardView, put it in a RecyclerView, and use the GridLayoutManager. That way, it'd be easier for you to obtain what you want.

Comment: The cardview height is wrap content. The imageview's (the card's only child) height is match parent.

Answer (score 5):

As you're wanting three views per row, regardless of the width of the row, and you want them all to be square, you could use a custom CardView, and override onMeasure() to force a 1:1 aspect ratio.

```
package com.example.view;

public class SquareCardView extends CardView {

    public SquareCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int ignoredHeightMeasureSpec) {
        int newHeightMeasureSpec = widthMeasureSpec;
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, newHeightMeasureSpec);
    }

}
```

Then use:

```
<com.example.view.SquareCardView
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1">
  <ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/square1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/main_dark"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
</com.example.view.SquareCardView>
```

Not saying you *should*, but you *could*.

Comment: Worked only under the assumption that the screen won't rotate.
Now every time I rotate the screen the items get wrong dimensions.
@ataulm

Comment: It should still be a square, but a different sized square.

Comment: well yeah they are square but not the size I specified they are super small but thanks for the answer it will work for portrait only apps.